# Model for survey with many mostly static questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc

As a step of a wizard process, I need to collect answers to 32 questions that will mostly not change (maybe once every couple years).  Each question can be answered yes or no, and then the ones that are yes require an explanation.

The naive approach is to have model properties for Question1Response, Question1Explanation, Question2Response, Question2Explanation... but this makes mapping from viewmodel to model and back painful.  Also the validation would require 32 ifs.  However, the view is very simple -- just a lot of Html.RadioButtonFor and Html.TextBoxFor.  Also, this aligns with the recipient of this data (a webservice that has parameters for each question and response).

I'm inclined to represent the responses as an IList of QuestionResponse objects that have a question number, response, and explanation.  This means mapping from viewmodel to model and back is simple, and validation is easy.  The view is a little ugly -- I end up writing a method that does something like Questions.Single(q => q.QuestionNumber.equals("1")), but it becomes much shorter since it's now a loop.  However, I'd have to store the survey questions in the model, and the app doesn't use a database but I could do something like build them up in the constructor...

Also, the question numbers are not just a linear progression, some of them will be things like "7b", so for validation I'd need to store a list of all of the questions that should be there.

How should I structure this model?

Comment: Use a database, it's not hard to implement and that way you could use EF and that way you could quite easily save data/etc (it's what db's are for!) - plus it would stop you from hardcoding everything (and hence much easier to update!)

Comment: The questions can come from a webservice or an XML file or whatever, it doesn't really matter.  Adding one would still require regenerating the webservice proxy.  The real question is: How should the validate method work?  The answer may be something similar to 1. get list of all question numbers from somewhere  2. go through and make sure each exists and if it's a yes, that it has an explanation.  But I'm interested if there's a better idea.

Comment: once you get your model sent to 'create/save/whatever actionMethod (which receives the model object of type modelData), use it to check there if 'object.CBox !null' - as you will still have to check all of the values :9

Comment: I don't know what you mean here.  Although the list strategy makes mapping very easy a user could craft an html post such that a question is missing, or the same question appears twice, etc, and the model binder will happily bind it to a viewmodel in the post action as it should.  Anyway, I can see how to deal with that, but it seemed weird that I don't find any examples of this sort of thing online, but it may just be that people don't frequently have models with a set of 32 object properties that all must be there.

Comment: that's because if you use a db, the modelstate will be auto generated, and hence if content is missing, it won't allow you to accept and go further (if NOT NULL is specified in the db schema)

Comment: I disagree.  I could set up a relationship between Responses and Questions and then (depending on orm) my Response objects will have a QuestionId or QuestionRef value but I can fiddle the value in the hidden input in the form however I want and it'll be happily bound.  Where the data comes from is inconsequential here.  There's no way to specify "there must be a row corresponding to each row in this other table" which is why I'd have to write validation to do that.

Comment: Have you looked at the line:  `if(ModelState.IsValid)` ? It means that all conditions of your model are successful (i.e. you have completed the model).